# How to display array from a query in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, rest

I am building a *rest api* from my database, but the values i am getting is not what I want.

My Code

This function gets the values from the database and returns the value in json format:

```
 public function index()
{
    $data = Books::all(['id','authors']);
    return response()->json(
                array(
                    'status_code' => $this->status_code,
                    'status' => $this->status, 
                    'data' => $data
                )
            );
}
```

Output

```
{
"status_code": 200,
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "authors": "[Kendra McLaughlin]"

    }
 }
```

Instead of this

```
{
"status_code": 200,
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "authors": [
            Kendra McLaughlin
          ]

    }
}
```

Comment: What about `$data = Books::get(['id','authors']);`?

Comment: It gives the same values. It did not work for me.

Comment: No way you're getting `"authors": "[Kendra McLaughlin]"`, you made it up.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ where can I look at how to save it the right way. any tutorial?

Comment: From the looks of it, you could make a relationship, something like what LucasPace suggests in the answer below. But I do not know anything about your application to say more. [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch)

Comment: I think you don't have a separate table for authors. If you stored authors into books table, then what is your authors column type? JSON or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably saving the authors as a string in a column. This is a wrong approach, you cannot save an array as a string. I suggest you learn about [Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).